# Which component is this?

Tags: components, dc-dc-converter, converter

[image: DC DC Converter?]

I salvaged a few components like that from some old ISA Ethernet card (10Base2 + 10BaseT combos), many years ago. If my memory doesn't fail, those boards were replaced by 1995, I kept them, and dismantled them somewhere by 2004...

Now I just found the time ;-) for asking about it. It´s a DIP package (fits perfectly on a breadboard).

I did some googling, I founded that it is a DC-DC converter, but I found no datasheets for those 20+ years old obsolete components...

There are clearly labeled pins VCC, IN, OUT, and G.

What could be the pins 1, 2, 3, 4?

What could be the search terms in order to find information about this or a similar device?

I'm pretty sure that I will not find an use for this, but, I think you'll understand, this is not my objective.

I sincerely hope that I didn't hurt your eyes (not so much) with those words that I wrote in a language that, obviously, is not my home language. :-)

Comment: Maybe a integrated power supply module.

Comment: If I wanted to know, here's where I would start... http://www.jotrin.com/product/mfg/ZUAJEN It probably means an enquiry to the mfg. the "datasheet" link leads nowhere useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably a DC-DC converter. 9V isolated output most likely, not sure about the input voltage. See [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-piece-GS-2IX-9-DC-DC-MODULE-2W-FOR-LAN-ETHERNET-isolated-9V-IEEE-NEW-/271747494503) ephemeral eBay listing for similar products.

If the first character in the part number is a 5, then maybe 5V in, and the 075 could indicate 7.5V out, but 9V was more common. Try hooking 5V to it, with some reasonable load on the output such as 1K and see what voltage you measure.

Comment: Spehro, eBay links don't make good references.  There are plenty of regular suppliers of DC-DC converters that can be used as reference.  They provide datasheets, and the link should not die in a month when an eBay auction expires.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yes, I know (hence the ['ephemeral'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ephemeral) qualifier), but these were specifically aimed at the LAN application. Since those boards have not been made for >10 years I don't think there is a valid contemporary link.

Comment: But if Nick says your link can't qualify, you should better start thinking about seppuku. Otherwise why would he bother?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as a **filter module** (based on DC converter), this could be the reason for the pins 1,2,3 and 4 of your DIP. This kind of filters were used often for 10BaseT boards.

[image]